# mysql 1064 error SYNTAX ERROR

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax-error, mysql-error-1064

I keep getting this error every time i try to create a table in my sql database:

Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` ( `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `' at line 2

Could I get some help with this?

```
use luke_f_db
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
 `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `trn_date` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 );
```

Comment: `use luke_f_db` ? `mysqli_select_db()` or adequate?

Comment: Throw a semicolon after `USE` (or indeed, do that outside the query, best in the connection statement).

Comment: 50 characters is not enough for some email addresses. Use `VARCHAR(255)` for most fields unless you have a very compelling reason not to, the storage cost is usually zero.

Comment: One day you'll develop an eye for missing semicolons and mistakes like this will become obvious. Until then pay very close attention to what MySQL is saying and look for issues just before where it's complaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an error with your `use` command. Add an ; behind the first line or just check if the database exists and your account has access to it.

The CREATE Code worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could run only one command per query**. The mySQL command line client allows you to split multiple commands with *;* but still runs them sequentially.

Remove the `use luke_f_db` line. The database to be used should be selected within the connect command. See http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_connect.asp:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
```

The database name is the last argument to mysqli_connect.

The same information is found in the official PHP documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

** Some mySQL client implementations also allow multiple commands in one call, but you should avoid it. Using this feature in a script isn't portable to other databases and you won't ever know which of your commands triggered an error if one occurs.

Comment: Please, whenever possible link to the official documentation for PHP.

Comment: It's not that obvious in this case: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php and http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: Sorry. Links are fixed now.

Comment: Not a problem, just trying to help. To keep things neat you can use the `[...](...)` notation to link directly to functions. Less messy than having giant, sprawling URLs in the middle of your answer.